# Automatically restart Android application after replacing itself

Tags: android, apk, android-package-managers, android-install-apk

I have an Android application that installs an update and replaces itself via `PackageManager` but I haven't found a way to automatically open itself afterwards since mainly it isn't running to receive any broadcasts / services etc. I have signature-level permissions but I don't think it helps. I'm running Android 6.0.1.

I've tried to do `pm install -r packagename.apk ; am start -n packagename/MainActivity` to chain commands, but it doesn't help to restart mainly because the app is killed before it can start itself.

I'm not looking for PackageManager "open" and "cancel" but an automatic restart.

I also could reboot the device and run it afterwards?

**How do I automatically restart Android application after replacing itself?**

**Update**

I ended up just using the package manager "done" and "open" dialog since I couldn't find a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a simple broadcast for application package update with an intent filter of `android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`.

Add this to your manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AppUpdateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And create broadcast receiver e.g AppUpdateReceiver.kt to relaunch app.

```
class AppUpdateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.i(tag, "App Updated, Relauncing...")

        val intent = Intent(context?.applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        context?.startActivity(intent)
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I couldn't rely  on any code in the activity since those receiver's won't run if the app isn't running (it already replaced itself).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Runtime execution instead of an App process. (Tested on a rooted device)

```
    private static void install(String apkPath) {
        System.out.println("Installing APK please... " + apkPath);
        try
        {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"su 0 ", "pm install -r "+apkPath+ " && am start -n com.example/com.example.activity.MainActivity"});
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Finished installing APK");
    }
```